# Evaluate/Refactor my ASP.NET XSS Security Helper Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, regex

I am maintaining a site with significant security concerns and I wrote a helper class for validating potential XSS attacks.  The `ValidateRequest` method is meant to evaluate the `HttpRequest` for any potential issues, and if issues are found, redirect the user to the same page, but in a away that is not threatening to the application.

The application is being evaluated by [HP WebInspect](https://www.fortify.com/products/web_inspect.html).  Their initial review included two regular expressions:

1. The "Regex for a simple XSS attack"

   `/((\%3C) <)((\%2F) \/)*[a-z0-9\%]+((\%3E) >)/ix`
2. The "Paranoid regex for XSS attacks"

   `/((\%3C) <)[^\n]+((\%3E) >)/I`

The regular expression I am using is a more stringent C# adaptation of the paranoid regex.  I prefer to err on the side of caution, so I would rather risk denying valid requests than allowing an invalid request to be processed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

public static class XssSecurity
{

public const string PotentialXssAttackExpression = "(http(s)*(%3a|:))|(ftp(s)*(%3a|:))|(javascript)|(alert)|(((\\%3C) <)[^\n]+((\\%3E) >))";

private static readonly Regex PotentialXssAttackRegex = new Regex(PotentialXssAttackExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

public static bool IsPotentialXssAttack(this HttpRequest request)
{
    if(request != null)
    {
        string query = request.QueryString.ToString();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) && PotentialXssAttackRegex.IsMatch(query))
            return true;
        if(request.HttpMethod.Equals("post", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            string form = request.Form.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form) && PotentialXssAttackRegex.IsMatch(form))
                return true;
        }
        if(request.Cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(HttpCookie cookie in request.Cookies)
            {
                if(PotentialXssAttackRegex.IsMatch(cookie.Value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }               
    return false;
}

   public static void ValidateRequest(this HttpContext context, string redirectToPath = null)
   {
       if(context == null || !context.Request.IsPotentialXssAttack()) return;

       // expire all cookies
       foreach(HttpCookie cookie in context.Request.Cookies)
       {
           cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
           context.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
       }

       // redirect to safe path
       bool redirected = false;
       if(redirectToPath != null)
       {
           try
           {
               context.Response.Redirect(redirectToPath,true);
               redirected = true;
           }
           catch
           {
               redirected = false;
           }
       }
       if (redirected) 
           return;

       string safeUrl = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Replace(context.Request.Url.Query, string.Empty);
       context.Response.Redirect(safeUrl,true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some general idea:

1. Use [guard statements](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) instead of big `if` blocks.
2. Extract the `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) && PotentialXssAttackRegex.IsMatch(query)` condition to a method.
3. Extract individual checks to distinct methods. The `IsPotentialXssAttack` will be quite easy to read and the code of different validations will not be mixed in one big method.
4. I'd create an `expireAllCookies` helper method too.

The final code of the first method would look like this (I haven't tested nor compiled):

```
public static bool IsPotentialXssAttack(this HttpRequest request) {
    if (request == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isPotentialXssAttackQuery(request)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (isPotentialXssAttackFormOrAnything(request)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (isPotentialXssAttackCookie(request)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


public static bool isPotentialXssAttackQuery(this HttpRequest request) {
    string query = request.QueryString.ToString();
    if (isMatch(query)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool isMatch(string input) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) {
        return false;
    }
    return PotentialXssAttackRegex.IsMatch(query);
}

// TODO: rename it
public static bool isPotentialXssAttackFormOrAnything(this HttpRequest request) {
    if (!request.HttpMethod.Equals("post", 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
        return false;
    }

    string form = request.Form.ToString();
    if (isMatch(form)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool isPotentialXssAttackCookie(this HttpRequest request) {
    if (request.Cookies.Count <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach (HttpCookie cookie in request.Cookies){
        if (isMatch(cookie.Value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1, @palacsint, clearly all good suggestions.  I like that when you apply this kind of refactoring the things being tested become much more explicit to other developers.  I noticed we can even go further and write, `public static bool IsPotentialXssAttack(this HttpRequest request) { return request != null && (isPotentialXssAttackQuery(request) || isPotentialXssAttackFormOrAnything(request) || isPotentialXssAttackCookie(request)); }`.  **However, did you notice any potential flaws in the actual functionality for mitigating XSS attacks?**

Comment: I don't prefer long conditions with lots of `||`s. I think it's harder to read than single `if`s. I didn't notice any flaws in the XSS logic, unfortunately I'm not too familiar with this field.

Comment: I guess that's personal preference.  To me it's easier to read, b/c my brain automatically translates || to " or " and && to " and ", so it sounds like plain english

Comment: e.g. imagine: `public static class Syntax
    {
        public static bool Or<T>(this bool value, T candidate, Func<T, bool> predicate) { return value || predicate(candidate); }
        public static bool And<T>(this bool value, T candidate, Func<T, bool> predicate) { return value && predicate(candidate); }
    }` .  Then you can do `return (request != null).And(isPotentialXssAttackQuery(request).Or(request,isPotentialXssAttackFormOrAnything).Or(request,isPotentialXssAttackCookie);` ...  I'd say that's a pretty readable single line